# Select only n number of characters from VARCHAR(MAX) field

Tags: sql-server, max, varchar

I have a field with datatype VARCHAR and MAX length.
However, I just want to print only the first 2000 characters from that field.
I cannot use VARCHAR(2000) as the datatype for the field upon table creation since there are a records exceeding this length and as you might all know, this results in a 'String or binary data would be truncated' error.

What I'm doing is sending an email report which may get too lengthy because of that field so I just want to output the first 2000 characters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use substring.

```
select SUBSTRING(yourcolumnname,0,2000) from yourtablename
```

Comment: or `left(yourcolumnname, 2000)` is equivalent